# How to use "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider" with Microsoft Active Directory Certificate Services?

Tags: active-directory, cryptography, certificate-authority, mscapi

I want to setup Microsoft Active Directory Certificate Services to use "**Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider**". 
Target: Windows 2016 server Data Center edition x64 running on VirtualBox. (Tested also on Win 2008 server x64)

"certutil -csplist" command displays this CSP as available CSP. 
Here is the Registry screenshot of the Cryptography Provider List:
[Registry - Cryptography Provider List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ufgr.png)

In AD CS Configuration wizard:

At Role Sevices step I have selected "Certification Authority".
At the "Cryptography for CA" step **the "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider" is missing** in the "Select a cryptographic provider" combobox. This CSP supports sha-256 algorithm. 
Please note: I don't want to use CNG providers.
Screenshots about the CSP provider list:

- [AD CS Configuration - Cryptography for CA step - CSP List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1DUG.png)
- [AD CS Configuration - Cryptography for CA step - CSP List
  continued](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8rn8.png)

Background info:

I'm developing a **custom CSP (Cryptographic service provider)** (not CNG). My CSP supports sha-256 so I need to set CSP Provider Type as "Type 024" (PROV_RSA_AES). But it is seems that "AD CS configuration" skips providers that have 024 as type. 
If I specify "Type 001" (PROV_RSA_FULL) for my custom CSP, then "AD CS configuration" displays my CSP in the provider list, but shows only sha1 in the hash algorithms and my sha-256 algorithm is missing. It is seems that AD CS configuration only supports sha-256 for CNG providers and skips legacy providers sha-256 implementation.

How to fix this issue?
How to use "Type 024" (PROV_RSA_AES) provider type in "AD CS configuration"?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi there was an error like this: Error: Provider DLL failed to initialize correctly./dailybuildsbranches/CSP_4_0/CSPbuild/CSP/samples/CPCrypt/Enroll.cpp:445: 0x8009001D. How can you fix it? Can't create Microsoft Enchanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider certificate on Linux.